# How can I calculate the contentsize of UItextView in which the text are dynamically added………

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uitextview

I ve an UIScrollview ,in which I ve placed UIImageView and UITextView..Here I add the data to the UITextView dynamically…I want to scroll  both the image and the text at the same time .It works fine..I ve assigned the contentsize of the UITextView to the contentsize of the UIScrollView…..Since I am adding the data dynamically I can't use the standard values..Any samples to find the contentsize of UITextView????

Answer (score 0):

*UITextView* is a subclass of *UIScrollView*. So you can directly use the *contentSize* method,

```
CGSize _contentSize = textView.contentSize;
float _height = _contentSize.height;
```

Comment: how can i assign the CGSize to content Size(content height is in float).

Comment: You can get *height* from *contentSize*. See my edited answer!